# Accessibility Scrolls Left and Right with WKWebView

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I am looking for a way to override what happens when a user does an accessibility scroll (three finger scroll with VoiceOver enabled) to the left or right in a WKWebView on iOS. I tried subclassing WKWebView and overriding goBack(), goForward(), and accessibilityScroll(...). My subclass methods do not get called. I also tried implementing accessibilityScroll(...) in my view controller, but that method did not get called either.

Ideally I want to continue letting WKWebView handle three finger scrolls up and down, but add my own behavior when a user three finger scrolls to the left or right.

Comment: Would a `SwipeGestureHandler` work for you? Using `numberOfTouches` and `direction` you could detect an `accessibilityScroll`. However, this won't work if you need to do something continuously while the user is scrolling, but only once when the gesture is detected.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures/handling_swipe_gestures

Otherwise, overriding `touchesBegan(_:with:)` etc. might work? However, I never tried this with `WKWebView`...

Comment: Thanks, @Flo. That might work, but honestly that looks like it would add more complexity than I would like.

Answer (score 0):

You could try capturing the accessibility scroll of the WebViews scrollView

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.scrollView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    override func accessibilityScroll(_ direction: UIAccessibilityScrollDirection) -> Bool {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```